# Are questions regarding drafting on topic here?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions, on-topic

Just found this Engineering stack-exchange site.  From browsing the help and meta, it seems this is pretty new.  I would imagine some, or most, of the users here are familiar with Eng-Tips as well - and in eng-tips there are many (maybe too many?!) sub-forums for different disciplines, software use, etc.

I'm wondering, since I can't seem to find another SE site for drafting, if questions related to drafting are on topic for this site?

---

### Specifically:

Are questions regarding general best practices in drafting e.g. leader positions, text size, use of notes, crossing leaders, multi page layouts, orthographic construction, etc, etc. on-topic?

What about questions related to interpreting and adhering to industry standards, e.g. DRF construction in accordance with ASME Y14.5-2009, True-position vs concentricity, etc.

How about as they pertain to specific engineering software, e.g. drafting in Catia, Solidworks, PRO-E, AutoCAD, etc.

---

These topics take up more than one whole sub-forum over on eng-tips, but sometimes it's hard to find an answer to a question asked on those forums.

I think the SE Q&A format is perfect for these kinds of topics, just want to know if they are on topic here.

Answer (score 8):

Focused questions on drafting would be on-topic.

Fishing expeditions about drafting would be off-topic as they're too broad.

---

Example focused question:

> Standard XYZ123 states "Foo ..." which I interpret to mean such and such.  However, I have seen conflicting interpretations where it means something else.  What would be the correct interpretation of that section of the standard in this particular case?

Example fishing expedition:

> I'm looking for the best practices when it comes to drafting a concrete slab for a patio.

---

Good questions focus on specific, answerable things and provide a measure of context based upon what the asker already knows or think they know.

Overly broad questions are easily accused of lacking research and are the sort of thing you'd throw at your favorite search engine at the beginning of your research.